# How to add icons in Ninja Form

Tags: html, css, wordpress, ninja-forms

I created a contact form in Ninja Form. But I want to customize the form exactly like the attached screenshot "form-1.jpg". I followed Ninja forms documentation and applied the "nf-icons in the custom class names under display settings but I didn't achieve the exact result. Can somebody help me, please?

Please note:
form-1.jpg - make it like that
form-2.jpg - what I got the result

[forn-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PL5xc.png)
[form-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8iDF.png)